# Mapper Dto to Entity in EF using self many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have a project with 4 classes:Direction, Area, Section and Local. Direction have many areas, Area have many sections and section have many locals. Local have positives locals and negatives locals, therefore Local entity will have a self many to many relationship. I'm using Automapper for convert LocalDto to Local, but when i try to update this entity with positives locals and/or negatives locals inserted, the system generate this exception:

> **The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.**

So, they are my mapper classes for my entities:

*******DirectionMapper*******

```
public static class DirectionMappers
{
    public static void SettingMappingDirectionToDirectionDto()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Direction, DirectionDto>()
        .ForMember(directionDto => directionDto.AreasDtosList,
            mc => mc.MapFrom(direction => direction.AreasCollection));

    }

    public static void SettingMappingDirectionDtoToDirection()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DirectionDto, Direction>()
        .ForMember(direction => direction.AreasCollection,
             mc => mc.MapFrom(directionDto => directionDto.AreasDtosList));
    }

    public static void SettingMappingDirectionToString()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Direction, string>().ConvertUsing(direction => direction.Name ?? string.Empty);
    }
}
```

********AreaMapper**********

```
  public class AreaMappers
{
    public static void SettingMappingAreaToAreaDto()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Area, AreaDto>()
            .ForMember(areaDto => areaDto.SectionsDtosList, mc => mc.MapFrom(area => area.SectionsCollection))
            .ForMember(areaDto => areaDto.DirectionDto, mc => mc.MapFrom(area => area.Direction));

    }
    public static void SettingMappingAreaDtoToArea()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<AreaDto, Area>()
            .ForMember(area => area.SectionsCollection, mc => mc.MapFrom(areaDto => areaDto.SectionsDtosList))
            .ForMember(area => area.Direction,mc=> mc.MapFrom(areaDto=> areaDto.DirectionDto));

    }

    public static void SettingMappingAreaToString()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Area, string>().ConvertUsing(area => area.Name ?? string.Empty);
    }
}
```

******SectionMapper*******************

```
public class SectionMappers
{
    public static void SettingMappingSectionToSectionDto()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Section, SectionDto>()
            .ForMember(sectionDto => sectionDto.LocalsDtosList, mc => mc.MapFrom(section => section.LocalsCollection))
            .ForMember(sectionDto => sectionDto.AreaDto, mc => mc.MapFrom(section => section.Area));
    }
    public static void SettingMappingSectionDtoToSection()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<SectionDto, Section>()
            .ForMember(section => section.LocalsCollection,
                mc => mc.MapFrom(sectionDto => sectionDto.LocalsDtosList))
            .ForMember(section => section.Area, mc => mc.MapFrom(sectionDto => sectionDto.AreaDto));

    }

    public static void SettingMappingSectionToString()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Section, string>().ConvertUsing(section => section.Name ?? string.Empty);
    }
}
```

******LocalMapper (the main course)******

```
public static class LocalMappers
{
    public static void SettingMappingLocalToLocalDto()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Local, LocalDto>()
                        .ForMember(localDto => localDto.PositivesLocalsDtos,
                                   mc => mc.MapFrom(local => local.PositivesLocals)
                                   )
                        .ForMember(localDto => localDto.NegativesLocalsDtos,
                                   mc => mc.MapFrom(local => local.NegativesLocals)
                                   )

             .ForMember(localDto => localDto.SectionDto, mc => mc.MapFrom(local => local.Section));


    }
    public static void SettingMappingLocalDtoToLocal()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<LocalDto, Local>()
            .ForMember(local => local.PositivesLocals,
                mc => mc.MapFrom(localDto => localDto.PositivesLocalsDtos)
            )
            .ForMember(local => local.NegativesLocals,
                mc => mc.MapFrom(localDto => localDto.NegativesLocalsDtos)
            )

            .ForMember(local => local.Section, mc => mc.MapFrom(localDto => localDto.SectionDto));
    }

    public static void SettingMappingLocalToString()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Local, string>().ConvertUsing(local => local.Number ?? string.Empty);
    }

}
```

Well, this's a service method for Local update:

```
 public AppOperationResult Update(int id, LocalDto localDto)
    {
        var appOperationResult = CommunValidations.IsDtoNull(localDto);
        if (appOperationResult != null) return appOperationResult;

        var tupleValidation = localDto.IsModelDtoValidateForUpdate(id);
        var isValidate = tupleValidation.Item1;

        if (isValidate)
        {
            if (TryUpdateLocalFromLocalDto(id, localDto)) return AppOperationResult.Successful();
        }
        string messageError = tupleValidation.Item2;
        return AppOperationResult.WithError(messageError);
    }
```

And these are the methods I did to add positive and negative locals (i call them AdjacentLocals):

```
 public AppOperationResult AddAdjacentLocalsToLocal(AdjacentLocalsToLocalDto adjacentLocalsToLocal)
    {
        var localDto = adjacentLocalsToLocal.LocalToModify;
        var appOperationResult = CommunValidations.IsDtoNull(localDto);
        if (appOperationResult != null) return appOperationResult;
        var tupleValidation = localDto.IsModelDtoValidate();
        var isValidate = tupleValidation.Item1;

        if (isValidate)
        {
            if (TryToAddAdjacentLocalsToLocal(adjacentLocalsToLocal, localDto))
                return AppOperationResult.Successful();
        }
        string messageError = tupleValidation.Item2;
        return AppOperationResult.WithError(messageError);
    }

    private bool TryToAddAdjacentLocalsToLocal(AdjacentLocalsToLocalDto adjacentLocalsToLocal, LocalDto localDto)
    {
        var positiveLocals = adjacentLocalsToLocal.PositiveLocals;
        var negativeLocals = adjacentLocalsToLocal.NegativeLocals;

        var positiveslocalsRepeated = positiveLocals.Intersect(localDto.PositivesLocalsDtos);
        positiveLocals.RemoveAll(x => positiveslocalsRepeated.Contains(x));

        var negativeslocalsRepeated = negativeLocals.Intersect(localDto.NegativesLocalsDtos);
        negativeLocals.RemoveAll(x => negativeslocalsRepeated.Contains(x));

        localDto.PositivesLocalsDtos = new List<LocalDto>(positiveLocals);
        localDto.NegativesLocalsDtos = new List<LocalDto>(negativeLocals);

        return TryUpdateLocalFromLocalDto(localDto.Id, localDto);
    }

    private bool TryUpdateLocalFromLocalDto(int idLocal, LocalDto localDto)
    {
        var local = _localServices.GetById(idLocal);
        local.PositivesLocals.Clear();
        local.NegativesLocals.Clear();
        _localServices.Update(local);
        if (local != null)
        {
            localDto.Id = idLocal;
            var localUpdated = _mappingServices.Map(localDto, local);
            _localServices.Update(localUpdated);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

********LocalDto*************

```
 public class LocalDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public float Volumen { get; set; }

    public int NumberMaxPeople { get; set; }

    public SectionDto SectionDto { get; set; }       

    public List<LocalDto> PositivesLocalsDtos { get; set; }

    public List<LocalDto> NegativesLocalsDtos { get; set; }
}
```

I'm working using ASP.NET WEB API philosophy,that's why I pass the list of adjacent places with a JSON (correctly), because I think the relationship between the objects in the lists with the database record is lost, but I do not understand why, since these local DTOs they are mapped correctly and return the corresponding local object. However, when I update a local with out a any list of positives or negatives locals, no problem.. so i think that problem is with the self many to many relationship.

I have traced the code several times, I check if all the entities have their relationships and everything seems to be fine, but when I try to update the Local entity inserting adjacents locals(positive and negative local) gives me the error that I mentioned above. So, i . I await your answers.Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is the following some entity entity framework that is not linking the existing sections in your database when you use the service of automapper, so I suggest that in your Dto not use the relationships for the other dto, for example:

```
public class LocalDto
```

{
    public int Id { get; set; }

```
public string Number { get; set; }

public float Volumen { get; set; }

public int NumberMaxPeople { get; set; }

public SectionDto SectionDto { get; set; }       

public List<LocalDto> PositivesLocalsDtos { get; set; }

public List<LocalDto> NegativesLocalsDtos { get; set; }
```

}

change it to :

```
 public class LocalDto
```

{
    public int Id { get; set; }

```
public string Number { get; set; }

public float Volumen { get; set; }

public int NumberMaxPeople { get; set; }

public int SectionId { get; set; }       

public List<LocalDto> PositivesLocalsDtos { get; set; }

public List<LocalDto> NegativesLocalsDtos { get; set; }
```

}

and you must also change the mapper associated with these entities,this must be removed from the class LocalMappers,

```
 .ForMember(localDto => localDto.SectionDto, mc => mc.MapFrom(local => local.Section));
```

This solution is for all your Dtos that have relations, link them to the id of the entity with which it is related not with the Dtos
I hope I've helped

Comment: Hi, I did what you tell me but I keep giving the same error when I try to add adjacent locals to LocalDto... what else can I do :(